# Product weight attribute automaticlly add four zero

Tags: magento, attributes

i'm new to magento. i try to use product weight attribute KG, how do i do this..

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did.

in attributes.phtml

```
<li>
    <?php
      if ($_product->getWeight() > 0) {
        $_theweight = $_product->getWeight();
        $_weightstr = number_format($_theweight, 0);
        echo '<span class="label">' . __('Weight') . ' : </span>';
        echo '<span class="data adss" id="childrenWeight">' . $_weightstr . ' Kg</span>';
       }
      ?>
</li>
```

and everything working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Weight attribute has `decimal` backend type. It is used to calculate total weight of a quote, used in shipping price calculations for some shipping methods.

You'll have to adjust your theme to output weight in desired format. You can simply cast attribute value to float to get rid of trailing zeros.

```
echo (float) 1.0000; // Outputs: 1
echo (float) 1.0100; // Outputs: 1.01
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i did it with php number_format(); its working, i have posted the answer